Wait for a recursive function to complete
I have having a recursive function and want to execute another function only when recursive function completed. My code is:
ngOnInit() {
    this.func1(this.myArray.length).then(()=>{
      this.func2()
    }).catch()    
  }

  func1(len: number) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('in function func 1 ---  ',this.myArray.length);
        if (len > 0) {
          this.myArray.pop();
          this.func1(this.myArray.length).then().catch();
        }
      }, 1000);
      resolve('func1 completed');
    });
  }

  func2(){
    console.log('in function func  2')
  }

StackBlitz
Output in console:
in function func 2
in function func 1 --- 2
in function func 1 --- 1
in function func 1 --- 0

It should be like below:
in function func 1 --- 2
in function func 1 --- 1
in function func 1 --- 0
in function func 2

What is wrong here?

The recursive call isn't part of the promise chain, you'd need something like this.func1(this.myArray.length).then(resolve). This is nothing to do with TS or Angular, just basic JS.

What is .then().catch() meant to achieve?

Your code suffers from the broken promise issue.
Firstly, the resolve('func1 completed') gets run ignoring the timeout.
Secondly, the func1 function does not connect to the inner (recursive) call.
You can fix the issue by returning (resolving) inner calls to the caller:
  ngOnInit() {
    this.func1(this.myArray.length)
      .then(() => this.func2())
      .catch((e) => console.error('error', e));
  }

  func1(len: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log('in function func 1 ---  ', this.myArray.length);
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (len > 0) {
          this.myArray.pop();
          // resolve(sth) works like return sth
          // return the inner promise to build a chain of promises
          resolve(this.func1(this.myArray.length)); 
        } else {
          resolve('func1 completed');
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  func2() {
    console.log('in function func  2');
  }

However, a better implementation for the func1 could be:
async func1(len: number) {
  console.log('in function func 1 ---  ', this.myArray.length);

  // wait here
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  if (len > 0) {
    this.myArray.pop();
    await this.func1(this.myArray.length);
  }

  return 'func1 completed';
}

Online playground
